# How to move attribute values from int to varchar table?

Tags: script, data, enterprise-1.10

I had to switch a dropdown field to a multiselect field. Previously the values were stored as integers (in catalog_product_entity_int) but now with multiselect I have to use varchar (catalog_product_entity_varchar).

I'm not sure how to move the data from one table to another with a data script so I would be glad if someone can provide me a possible solution or any thoughts on how to do it.

I googled already a bit but I guess I use the wrong search words..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

TO Change Single Select to Multiple Select:

```
UPDATE eav_attribute SET backend_model = 'eav/entity_attribute_backend_array',frontend_input = 'multiselect',backend_type = 'varchar',source_model = NULL WHERE eav_attribute.attribute_id = 136;
```

Copy from INT (Single Select Values) to VARCHAR:

```
insert into catalog_product_entity_varchar (entity_type_id, attribute_id, store_id, entity_id, value) select entity_type_id, attribute_id, store_id, entity_id, value from catalog_product_entity_int where attribute_id = 136 ;
```

Use your Attribute ID instead of `136`

`DELETE FROM catalog_product_entity_int WHERE attribute_id = 136;`

After copying values from INT to VARCHAR.

Answer (score 0):

As Subesh Pokhrel suggested the following solution includes his given statements.
I used the data upgrade script to solve the problem with the given statements

```
$installer = $this;
$conn = $installer->getConnection();
$attribute_id = $installer->getAttributeId('catalog_product', 'attribute_code');

$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO catalog_product_entity_varchar (entity_type_id, attribute_id, store_id, entity_id, value) SELECT entity_type_id, attribute_id, store_id, entity_id, value FROM catalog_product_entity_int WHERE attribute_id = :attribute_id");
$stmt->bindParam(':attribute_id', $attribute_id);
$stmt->execute();

$stmt = $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM catalog_product_entity_int WHERE attribute_id = :attribute_id");
$stmt->bindParam(':attribute_id', $attribute_id);
$stmt->execute();
```